# Command Prompt Wildcard File Delete Incorrectly Matching

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, delete-file

On a regular basis, I am trying to clean up some data folders for an ERP program prior to doing a backup and performing maintenance on the data tables. I've been using Windows Explorer to search for extraneous backup and temporary files prior to the full backup (the maintenance procedures create backup files during the process that aren't always removed), but I'd like to just run it all through a batch file to simplify and speed up the process. I'm filtering with the following:

***NGT????????????.old

*Wrk*????????????.m4t**

Also, the command I'm using:
**del /S /Q**

Both of these work perfectly though the search function within Explorer. The first one works correctly in a command prompt, but the second doesn't. The series of ?s are created by the ERP software as a time stamp, to indicate a copy of the original was created at that time. And the second * represents a one or two character user ID that indicates the user that created the file (it isn't all that important except that the character length isn't always the same). When I try to filter in the command prompt with that second filter, not only does it grab the files I want it to, but it also grabs the original source files which **DO NOT** have a time stamp on them. For example, the following file names:

File 1) AR_AgedInvoiceReportWrk.M4T
File 2) AR_AgedInvoiceReportWrkTB081615903027.M4T

File 2 is the only one that should be deleted, but it will delete both File 1 and File 2. I've even tried using two or three ?s instead of the second * just to see if a difference would occur, but it doesn't.

Does the command prompt not recognize the ? the way Explorer does? What am I missing?

Comment: "Does the command prompt not recognize the ? the way Explorer does?" The short answer to that is no. Read this first: [How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) and keep in mind that Cmd.exe pattern-matching is backward-compatible.

Comment: Forgot to mention this one as well: [Why does FindFirstFile find short names?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/20/440918.aspx). The best workaround I can suggest is to use PowerShell instead, which doesn't suffer from these backward compatibility quirks.

Answer (score 2):

DIR and it seems other tools match the short file name and the long filename.  Your short filenames have `wrk` as the leading characters and then you are matching a whole swag of any-character.

A solution is to use something like `DIR /b /a-d` and pipe it through `findstr` with a regexp, and that will match only the long filenames.

Comment: I edited the text above, but nothing actually has "Wrk" at the beginning. "Wrk" is always at the end of the short filenames. It's not distinguishing the short form the long. But here's the thing... There's a root directory with subdirectories, and all of these files will be in the subdirectories. Can this method reach into the subdirectories?

Comment: Of course if you change the question filespec mask then `wrk` will not be at the front.  If you state the task properly then you may get an appropriate batch solution.  There are many skilled people reading here who enjoy solving a task.